# playwright в cron-e не работает

Tags: парсер, webkit, chromium, playwright

Запуск происходит на VPS.
Итак, если запускать код без cron-a то все ок, сайты парсятся.
Когда я добавляю cron то все летит в кучу с ошибками. Вот что выдает мне мой лог

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/apars/nobr.py", line 39, in <module>
    povtor()
File "/apars/nobr.py", line 9, in povtor
    x = obr_cnt()   
File "/apars/obrzka_count.py", line 8, in obr_cnt
    id_mobile = parser()
File "/apars/parser_new.py", line 4, in parser
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'
```

Хотя в ubuntu все установлено и вот что показывает pip3 list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вот, например, у рута один питон, а у крона другой питон (соотв.. 3.9, 3.10). в одном из которых установлен требуемый модуль, а в другом нет.  вот варианты проверки https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-sys-platform-version-info/   ну еще допустимо проверить путь запуска (напр., /usr/bin/python3.9   /usr/local/bin/python3.9 командой which python3.9)

Comment: Да, скорее всего это и помогло. Спасибо!